# Mention getting an offer to the adcom when in waitlist

Tags: graduate-admissions

I got waitlisted at Northwestern University for their Master's in Analytics program. I recently received an offer to join the MSE in Data Science at the University of Pennsylvania. Should I email NU and let them know about my offer to have a chance of reconsideration?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that notifying them will change anything. And it might even work against you if they know  you have another possible situation already. There might be rules that prevent dropping you from the waitlist. But if not, you are more likely to be dropped than advanced.

They won't, in particular, put you ahead of another candidate rated higher on their list for learning of your other offer.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! I have heard different opinions on this matter but will likely stay put and hope for the best as you suggested.